# Why does the unique existential quantifier seem to allow weird behaviour?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm currently reading through an introductory book to proofs and have just stumled upon the *unique existential quantifier* $\exists!$
On the book as well as on Wikipedia it says that $\exists!$ has the following equivalence:

$$(\exists! x) \equiv (\exists x)A(x) ∧ (\forall y)(\forall z)(A(y) ∧ A(z) \Rightarrow y = z)$$

My question is the following: doesn't this last expression allow for weird behaviour? For example, $A(y)$ could be **True** and $A(z)$ be **False** and still have $y = z$ be **True**, without making the conditional $(A(y) ∧ A(z) \Rightarrow y = z)$ **False**. Does this hold up simply because of the fact that you will never both have $A(y)$ be **T**, $A(z)$ be **F** and $y = z$ be **T**?

Comment: Assume there are two $A$s: $a$ and $b$. In that case we have $A(a)$ and $A(b)$ and the antecedent is TRUE, while the consequent is FALSE if the two are **not** the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This should really be a comment, but it's too long.*

You ask:

> Does this hold up simply because of the fact that you will never both have $A(y)$ be $\top$, $A(z)$ be $\perp$ and $y=z$ be $\top$?

*(I've switched to more standard notation for true/false.)* Yes, you are correct, and this is due to the special logical properties of equality.

To unpack this, it may be helpful to consider a generalization of the unique existential quantifier. Suppose I have a binary relation symbol $E$ in my language; then the *$E$-unique existential quantifier* $\exists!_E$ is defined as follows:

$$\exists!_Ex\varphi(x)\quad\equiv\quad [\exists x\varphi(x)]\,\,\wedge\,\,[\forall x\forall y(\varphi(x)\wedge\varphi(y)\implies xEy)].$$

If you want to think about things graph-theoretically, this says that the set of $x$ satisfying $\varphi$ forms an ["$E$-clique"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)). We also have the *strong $E$-unique existential quantifier $\exists!^+_E$* defined as follows:

$$\exists!_E^+x\varphi(x)\quad\equiv\quad [\exists x\varphi(x)]\,\,\wedge\,\,[\forall x\forall y(\varphi(x)\wedge\varphi(y)\implies xEy)]\,\,\wedge\,\,[\forall x\forall y(\varphi(x)\wedge xEy\implies \varphi(y))].$$

Note the additional clause. Graph-theoretically, this says that the set of $x$ satisfying $\varphi$ forms a *maximal* $E$-clique.

These quantifiers can be very oddly behaved. For example, whenever $\exists!_E$ and $\exists!_E^+$ aren't the same we have some $a, b$ and some formula $\varphi$ such that $\exists!_Ex\varphi(x)$ holds,  $\varphi(a)$ and $aEb$ hold but $\varphi(b)$ fails; this is the situation you're worried about but with $=$ replaced with $E$. Indeed, this situation *characterizes* the phenomenon "$\exists!_E\not=\exists!_E^+$."

However, note that in the special case where we use $=$ for $E$ we gain the additional power of knowing how $=$ behaves. For example, $=$ satisfies the *substitution* property: $\varphi(x)$ and $x=y$ implies $\varphi(y)$. This immediately tells us that $\exists!_=$ and $\exists!_=^+$ are the same, and in particular the situation you're worried about *can't* happen.

The point is that by thinking about the "generalized" unique existential quantifiers, we see that your worry is avoided *not* because of anything fancy in the definition of the unique existential quantifier but rather the basic logical properties of equality.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what precise aspect of this you find weird... but it, in fact, cannot happen, because of the substitution property of equality; if $y=z$, then you get $A(z)$ by substituting $y \to z$ into $A(y)$, and so they have to be the same truth value.